# Llenar tabla HTML usando 3 Arrays PHP

Tags: php, html, html5

Escribo por un problema al momento de mostrar una tabla HTML usando 3 arrays distintos.

Explico un poco mi problema:

1. Tengo un arreglo donde obtengo unos ID's, estos ID's deben ir en el header de la tabla HTML, el resultado sera siempre 33 registros
2. Tengo otro arreglo donde obtengo zonas, en total son 82 registros.
3. Tengo un tercer arreglo donde obtengo el detalle.

Cuando armo la tabla en el header hago esto:

```
 $tabla ='<table class="tablalistado compact hover row-border order-column" id="'.$modulo_id.'">
            <thead><tr>
                <th class="text-center">Zona</th>';
                for ($encab = 0; $encab < sizeof($array_motsub); $encab++) { 
                    $tabla.='<th class="text-center">'.$array_motsub[$encab]['motivo'].'-'.$array_motsub[$encab]['submotivo'].'</th>';
                }

            $tabla.='</tr>
        </thead><tbody>';
```

Ahí me genera el header de mi tabla. Después cargo lo que serian mis zonas y hago lo siguiente:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array_zona);$i++) {            
            $tabla.='<tr><td>'.$array_zona[$i].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Ahí tengo una tabla armada con el header y una columna con todas la zonas algo mas o menos así:

```
Zona D-0 7-0 T-0 T-1 P-0
 1  
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Ahora, hay datos en cada zona que no aplica para el ID es decir al meter el arreglo detalle debería quedar algo así:

```
Zona D-0 7-0 T-0 T-1 P-0
 1    -  30  40  10  - 
 2   15  -    8   3  5
 3   -   -    1   -  -
 4   20   9  10   4  7
 5   13  -   -   78  43
 6   -   12  3    5   3
```

Donde el símbolo menos '-' es cuando no hay datos de esa zona para ese ID.

He probado un montón de cosas y no me funciona, no me agrega el guion correctamente, si no hay datos lo coloca en la columna incorrecta, el código final que tengo es así:

```
        $tabla ='<table class="tablalistado compact hover row-border order-column" id="'.$modulo_id.'">
            <thead><tr>
                <th class="text-center">Zona</th>';
                for ($encab = 0; $encab < sizeof($array_motsub); $encab++) { 
                    $tabla.='<th class="text-center">'.$array_motsub[$encab]['motivo'].'-'.$array_motsub[$encab]['submotivo'].'</th>';
                }

            $tabla.='</tr>
        </thead><tbody>';


        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array_zona);$i++) {            
            $tabla.='<tr><td>'.$array_zona[$i].'</td>';
            foreach ($array as $detalle => $value) {


                if( $array_zona[$i] == $value['zona'] && isset($value['indice'])  ){


                        $tabla.='<td>'.$value['contratos'].'</td>';


                }

            }

            $tabla.='</tr>';
        }


    $tabla.='</tbody></table>';
    echo $tabla;
```

**EDITO**
Agrego una imagen del resultado actual, donde se puede ver que no agrega los valores a donde corresponde

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**VUELVO A EDITAR IMAGEN**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero se entienda un poco mi planteamiento, en principio no debería ser complicado, pero realmente no he podido manejarlo correctamente.

Saludos y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Y cómo es que queda tu tabla actualmente con el código que tienes?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tan pronta, edite el post y coloque una imagen del resultado actual. Saludos

Comment: Los datos no concuerdan con la zona o no concuerdan con los ids?

Comment: Pregunta, ¿al `if( $array_zona[$i] == $value['zona'] && isset($value['indice'])  ){` no le faltaría un `else { $tabla.='<td>-</td>'; }` o algo parecido? No termino de comprender bien el código, pero parecería que sólo pones los valores cuando están presentes, y si no están presentes (que sería un guión) no pones nada.

Comment: Tienes razón, lo había puesto y lo quite, ahí va la imagen de cuando coloco en el else lo siguiente:

    else{ $tabla.='<td>-</td>';   }

Comment: Creo que el `else` debería tener una condición más dentro. ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo simplificado de los arrays de datos? Para que podamos reproducir el problema localmente

Comment: array de los ID's: 
array(33) {
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["motivo"]=>
    string(2) "1 "
    ["submotivo"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["indice"]=>
    string(3) "1-B"
  }

Comment: array detalle: array(2385) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["zona"]=>
    string(3) "050"
    ["motivo"]=>
    string(2) "  "
    ["submotivo"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["contratos"]=>
    string(2) "37"
    ["indice"]=>
    string(2) "-0"
  }

Array de zonas

rray(82) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "050"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "051"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "052"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "053"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use los datos de tu tabla de ejemplo para crear el código espero que se de ayuda.

```
<?php
// Varibles de los datos
$ids = array('D-0','7-0','T-0', 'T-1', 'P-0');
$zonas = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$detalles = array(
    array('zona' => 1, 'contratos' => 30, 'indice' => '7-0'),
    array('zona' => 1, 'contratos' => 40, 'indice' => 'T-0'),
    array('zona' => 1, 'contratos' => 10, 'indice' => 'T-1'),
    array('zona' => 2, 'contratos' => 15, 'indice' => 'D-0'),
    array('zona' => 2, 'contratos' => 8, 'indice' => 'T-0'),
    array('zona' => 2, 'contratos' => 3, 'indice' => 'T-1'),
    array('zona' => 2, 'contratos' => 5, 'indice' => 'P-0'),
    array('zona' => 3, 'contratos' => 1, 'indice' => 'T-0'),
    array('zona' => 4, 'contratos' => 20, 'indice' => 'D-0'),
    array('zona' => 4, 'contratos' => 9, 'indice' => '7-0'),
    array('zona' => 4, 'contratos' => 10, 'indice' => 'T-0'),
    array('zona' => 4, 'contratos' => 4, 'indice' => 'T-1'),
    array('zona' => 4, 'contratos' => 7, 'indice' => 'P-0'),
    array('zona' => 5, 'contratos' => 13, 'indice' => 'D-0'),
    array('zona' => 5, 'contratos' => 78, 'indice' => 'T-1'),
    array('zona' => 5, 'contratos' => 43, 'indice' => 'P-0'),
    array('zona' => 6, 'contratos' => 12, 'indice' => '7-0'),
    array('zona' => 6, 'contratos' => 3, 'indice' => 'T-0'),
    array('zona' => 6, 'contratos' => 5, 'indice' => 'T-1'),
    array('zona' => 6, 'contratos' => 3, 'indice' => 'P-0'),
);

// Se crear un matriz apartir del numero de zonas (Filas) y numero de ids (Columas)
$matriz = array_pad(array(), count($zonas), array_pad(array(), count($ids), "-"));

foreach ($detalles as $key => $value) {
    $z = array_search($value["zona"], $zonas);
    $i = array_search($value["indice"], $ids);
    $matriz[$z][$i] = $value["contratos"];
}
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Zona</th>
            <?php foreach ($ids as $key => $value) { ?>
               <th><?php echo $value; ?></th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($matriz as $key => $value) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $zonas[$key]; ?></td>
                <?php foreach ($value as $k => $v) { ?>
                    <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola @Mvochoa, me funciono perfecto, de verdad muchas gracias. Saludos

Comment: De nada amigo, igualmente saludos :)